# realize Bitset function whose param is long

Tags: java, bitset

The set() function of BitSet is set(int param).I am trying to realize Bitset function by sending a long type.Are there any API or tutorial? thanks.

```
BitSet mobiphoneUsers = new BitSet();

bitset.set(12311111111111111111L);

if(bitset.get(1231111111111111111L)) {
    System.out.println("1231111111111111L is mobiphone user");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'realize' Bitset function?

Comment: This is probably not what you want, since `BitSet`'s `set()` method will set the bit at the given offset to value 1 (and its argument is an `int`, so your `123L` will get downcast to an `int`. Care to explain what you want to do?

Comment: BitSet API is open source and it doesn't contain a method like set(long) so what are you trying to do??

Comment: Because of the Bitset is only support for type int

Comment: @fge Because of the Bitset is only support for type int.So I want to create a class support for long, and can get boolean result :(

Comment: @Felix I think there is a misinterpretation here. Do you actually want, in a bit set, that is a sequence of `0000...1...0000...1...`, for bit at offset 123 to be set to 1? For some reason I believe this is not what you want. Hence my initial question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a `BitSet` with more than 2 billion bits, I would guess that only a small fraction of those entries are set. For a "sparse" bit set like this you are better off using a `HashSet<Long>`.

```
HashSet<Long> bitset = new HashSet<Long>();

bitset.add(12311111111111111111L);

if(bitset.contains(1231111111111111111L)) {
    System.out.println("1231111111111111L is mobiphone user");
}
```

Comment: Because of the Bitset saving space, I use it.If the param type is long, which way is better? HashSet or custom Bitset? @Russell Zahniser

Comment: @Felix: If you have 1000 bits set in a `BitSet` of size 2,000,000,000, you use 250,000,000 bytes. A `HashSet` of the same values would probably use around 16,000 bytes. Basically, if less than about 5% of the possible values are set, then you have a "sparse" set and a hashed implementation will be more memory-efficient.

Comment: @Felix: saving space? Where do you see a `BitSet` saving any space at all? For most of them, the overhead of the `BitSet` object itself is more than its working contents. Don't ever worry about "saving space" in Java unless you really need to: more often than not it will do a better job than what you can do yourself.

Comment: SparseBitSet is the definitive solution to this problem:
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/SparseBitSet